# HoloLens 2 Emulator pixelated

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

The HoloLens 2 Emulator is pixelated (see screenshot 1). This makes the usage user unfriendly. I would like to achieve the state on screenshot 2. Any ideas?
[image]

[image]

According to the documentation, my local PC meets the requirements. My local PC has:

- x63 architecture
- 4 core CPU with 8 core in total
- 30 GB RAM
- Direct3D version is 12
- WDDM version is 2.7
- Windows 10 Enterprise with Hyper-V enabled

Comment: What is the version number of your HoloLens 2 Emulator? Is that upgraded to the latest release? Could you try to disable hardware graphics acceleration in the emulator Tools window to work around this issue?

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT Indeed turning off desktop graphics acceleration did it. If you like, reply to this thread so I can mark your solution. PS: Yes, I always use the latest release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware graphics acceleration may cause Holographic apps to crash on some systems with AMD or Intel graphics. Disabling hardware graphics acceleration in the emulator Tools window works around this issue. For more information please refer to: [Known Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-hololens-emulator#known-issues)